# How to add Query results to Combobox, Error with Combobox Items - Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, items

I currently try to add query values to my ComboBox in Access VBA. But it seems like they are always in a wrong format / wrongly added to the Combobox.

```
    Dim query As String
    Dim projectnr As String
    Dim projectint As Integer
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim counter As Long
    
    counter = 0
    'Get all Projectsnumbers
    query = "SELECT [tblExProjekte].[exwID], [tblExProjekte].[exwProjektnummer] FROM tblExProjekte WHERE Not IsNull([tblExProjekte].[exwProjektnummer]) ORDER BY [exwProjektnummer] DESC;" 'Query get Projectnumbers
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query)
    rs.MoveFirst
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then 'Check if Entry Exists from SELECT
        Do Until rs.EOF = True 'Loop all Projects
            projectnr = rs("exwProjektnummer")
            If Not IsEmpty(projectnr) And StartsWith(projectnr, "640") Then 'Check if Project
                projectcombobox.AddItem rs("exwProjektnummer") 'Add Item to ComboBox
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
            counter = counter + 1
        Loop
    End If
```

I get results like this, in the Combobox:

"64067923;'';64067721;'';64067405;'';64067255;'';64067234;'';64066905;'';64066875;'';64066861;'';64066860;'';64066676;'';64066674;'';64066673;'';64066636;'';64066426;'';64066373;'';64066220;'';64066209;'';64066190;'';64066169;'';64066127;'';64066090;'';"

on Access directly it seems that there are a lot of empty values in the Box
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaJX1.png)

since im new into access vba, i would be glad for any help

I currently try to add query values to my ComboBox in Access VBA. But it seems like they are always in a wrong format / wrongly added to the Combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Hy Tommy,

In the above case, it's easier to create a query directly in your combobox. It's more maintainable and no code is needed.
You can do this by going to the combobox and select Rowsource. In dutch at my side.

[image]

The Rowsource type should be : Table/Query

When you select the rowsource option; a query designer will open.
Here you can then select your table and select the rows you want to show / use.

[image]

Lets say you want to show the projectnummer and use the id field. You can go to the format field of the combobox and configure it as shown bellow :

[image]

Columns is set to 2
Column width is set to 0;3 cm
This means the first will be 0 cm ( not visible ) and the second 3 cm ( visible )

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks that would have been an more easier solution then mine!

I figured the Problem was not with my Code, but with my Combobox somehow broken, after deleting and adding a new one it works now...

Answer (score 0):

`rs("exwProjektnummer")` returns a recordset field, which can do funky things when adding this object directly to a collection.

Use

```
projectcombobox.AddItem rs("exwProjektnummer").Value
```

or since you have it in a string variable anyway,

```
projectcombobox.AddItem projectnr
```

But if your code isn't greatly simplified and your query is constant as shown, Mathias is correct:
just use the query as row source.